# imageView not showing ACS photo #appcelerator

Tags: javascript, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

Once opening profile page, I ran a Cloud.Users.showMe function. In this function I put this in

```
var upperppicview = Ti.UI.createImageView({
  image:'user.photo.urls.original',
  width: '70%',
    top: '10%',
    height: '80%',
    borderRadius: 5,
    left: '5%'
});
upperpview.add(upperppicview);
```

The view is there but not showing the image of the user, I have already uploaded the photo on arrowdb and passed the User(photo_id) the photo.id of the created photo.
The photo was uploaded, it seemed to be attached backend as the user had an image attached but was not showing the particular image(as seen in the attachment below). 
How do I show the image as I need to also do this for events.

[arrowdb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8nHQI.png)

Comment: I think the problem is on the image value. You might need to use it without the quotes. Like:
`image: user.photo.urls.original`
Also, try to log and open in browser your image url, to make sure it exists. You can do this: `console.log(user.photo.urls.original);`

Answer (score 2):

You put a string into your createImageView function.

Try this instead

```
var upperppicview = Ti.UI.createImageView({
  image:user.photo.urls.original,
  width: '70%',
    top: '10%',
    height: '80%',
    borderRadius: 5,
    left: '5%'
});
upperpview.add(upperppicview);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your given code, image property value should be image location. It would be local or remote URL.

When you assign like  **image:'user.photo.urls.original'** then image property value is string which is not local image or remote image locations that why its not working.

If you want to display from ACS server its store in **user** variable.

**user** is object so you need to set like **image:user.photo.urls.original** not **image:'user.photo.urls.original'**

Here is final code for image display in your apps will be

```
var upperppicview = Ti.UI.createImageView({
    image:user.photo.urls.original,
    width: '70%',
    top: '10%',
    height: '80%',
    borderRadius: 5,
   left: '5%'
   });

upperpview.add(upperppicview);
```

For more details please visit following link:

https://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.ImageView-property-image
https://docs.appcelerator.com/arrowdb/latest/#!/api/Users-property-photo

Thanks